# File Copy to network share fails when user does not have Write permissions to application folder

Tags: c#

I have a simple C# application that is used to copy files from a users temp folder to an SFTP server on the network.  The application lives in a network share and users access it via a mapped drive on their desktop.

The problem we are having is that if a user does not have Write permissions to the application folder the copy fails with the exception "unknown user name or bad password".

So, here is the scenario:

> > **Security Group A**: 
> >     Read & Execute
> >     List Folder Contents
> >     Read
> >
> > **Security Group B**:
> >     Modify
> >     Read & Execute
> >     List Folder Contents
> >     Read
> >     Write
> >
> > \\network.com\public\sftp_test  - network share for the application controlled by groups A&B
> >
> > i:\   - users mapped drive to above share

Code where exception occurs:

```
try
{
    NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential([serverusername], [password]);
    CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
    cache.Add(new Uri(@"\\[ip address]"), "Basic", creds);
    var sftpFile = string.Format(@"\\[ip address]\sftp\{0}_{1}.zip", [username], DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyhhssmm"));
    System.IO.File.Copy(zip, sftpFile);
    Console.WriteLine("File successfully sent to server!");
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
}
```

Any user in Security Group A attempting to copy a file receives the exception.

Any user in Security Group B attempting to copy a file receives the success message.

Is there something I am missing?

Should a users rights to the folder where the application lives matter?

Comment: Well as you said "the user does NOT have write permissions" the folder you are pointing at! even if you are passing a username and password, the fact the your group policy doesn't allow to user it will make your code fail.

Comment: Are you sure it is failing on the `Copy` command?  It doesn't sound like the kind of thing you'd get back from that.

Comment: M Patel - The files are being copied to a share on another server, this is why I am creating network credentials using an account that lives on the destination server and has all appropriate permissions.

Comment: Ok, is the PC on a different domain to the server?

Comment: It appears that our environment is not being properly maintained and there are changes in place on the SFTP server we are attempting to connect to that we were not aware of.  BTW, the testers that succeeded also had mapped drives to the server which is why they were succeeding.  With all mapped drives removed everyone now fails.  Sorry for jumping the gun folks.  Thanks for the help!